# Tizen Studio - Gear S3 - SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

I'm trying to run simple template native application on Gear S3. I have created certificate according to [Working with the Certificate Profile](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/native-tools/managing-projects/certificate-registration).

My Gear S3 is connected via wifi and showed correctly in Connection explorer.

I'm still getting error SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED[23] when running it. There are many unsolved topics with this error on the web.

Tizen Studio 1.0.1,
Gear S3's Tizen 2.3.2.0

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove all the certificates you've created already and follow [this guide](http://developer.samsung.com/z/develop/getting-certificates/create) carefully. I think, the problem is with certificate type i.e. you've created **Tizen** certificate instead of **Samsung** certificate.

Comment: I don't see the first blue screen anywhere in certificate manager. Am I using wrong studio version or missing plugin? Thank you!

Comment: Install Samsung Extension SDK.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you.

Comment: The updated URL for the Samsung Certificate guide is this: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/getting-certificates/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

According to:

https://wiki.tizen.org/SDK

````

Q: on tizen-studio CLI ?

error : 23
end process (fail)
processing result : SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED [23] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [3822]ms
cmd_ret:23

or IDE

Error code: SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED
Error message: SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED
Command: /usr/bin/pkgcmd -q -i -t tpk -p "/opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.*-arm.tpk"
Management: Check whether the package is modified illegally. If there is an installed package which has same name and different signature with your package, you can receive this error return also.

A:

Select / an other certificate from IDE

Check privileges with "sdb dlog" or certificates issues

sdb dlog | grep signature

E/PKGMGR_PARSER( 9735): pkgmgr_parser_signature.c: __ps_check_mdm_policy_by_pkgid(1056) > (ret != MDM_RESULT_SUCCESS) can not connect mdm server
W/CERT_SVC( 9834): SignatureValidator.cpp: check(432) > signature1.xml has got unrecognized Root CA certificate. Signature will be disregarded.
E/rpm-installer( 9834): coretpk-signature-validator.cpp: _coretpk_signature_validator_validate_signatures(148) > (valRes != ValidationCore::SignatureValidator::SIGNATURE_VERIFIED) validator.check() is failed, valRes=[-34]
E/rpm-installer( 9834): installer-util.c: _installer_util_get_configuration_value(600) > [signature]=[on]
E/rpm-installer( 9834): coretpk-installer.c: _coretpk_installer_install_package(3654) > _coretpk_signature_validator_validate_signatures(/opt/usr/data/pkgmgr/org.example.*/, org.example.*) failed. ret=[-34]

````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to removed existing certificates, just create a new certificate for particular device and mark it selected in Certificate manager when you are to work with S3.

I encountered same issue and its resolved now.